# If (x OR y) Performance

Tags: php, performance, if-statement

I have a performance related question regarding how PHP evaluates the OR operator in a conditional.

I have a conditional that calls 2 functions, both returning booleans:

The first is a simple, fast function - simpleFunction()

The second is a more intensive function that queries the DB - intensiveFunction()

I could write the conditional like this, so that if the first, simple function returned TRUE, the second more intense function would not be executed:

```
if ( simpleFunction() ) {
   // Do Stuff
} elseif ( intensiveFunction() ) {
   // Do the same stuff (redundant code)
}
```

My question is, when using and OR operator in a PHP conditional, if the first condition (on the left of the operator) is TRUE, will the second function (on the right side of the operator) be executed?

```
if ( simpleFunction() || intensiveFunction() ) {
    //Do Stuff
}
```

This conditional will be running inside a loop, so I would like to avoid running intensiveFunction() on every iteration.

Comment: Why don't you test it out and see?

Comment: The answer is no. Same if first of two && expressions evaluates to false.

Comment: Also called `short circuit` or `lazy` evaluation

Comment: @Neal - Yes, of course.  I couldn't think of a logical way to test this, but one just occurred to me.  Will post proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Neal pointed out, I should have just tested this:

```
$hasRun = 'Intesive Function Has NOT Run';

function simpleFunction() {
    return TRUE;    
}

function intensiveFunction() {
    $hasRun = 'Intesive Function Has Run';  
    return TRUE;
}

if ( simpleFunction() || intensiveFunction() ) {
    echo $hasRun;   
}

//Result: Intesive Function Has NOT Run function
```

So yes, once the first condition returns TRUE the conditional exits and the second condition is not evaluated.

Answer (score 6):

I *believe* that once a truthy is found in an **or** operation, then the statement ends and returns `true`,

Whereas in an **and** operation, it runs until it finds a falsey.

Comment: Don't believe, be sure ([it is as you say](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)).

Answer (score 2):

Additionally compare this script testing the various logical operators:

```
<pre>
<?php
function test($bool) {
    echo "I was executed\n";

    return $bool;
}

echo "<b>||-Operator</b>\n";
if (test(true) || test(true)) {
    ;
}

echo "<b>|-Operator</b>\n";
if (test(true) | test(true)) {
    ;
}

echo "<b>or-Operator</b>\n";
if (test(true) or test(true)) {
    ;
}

echo "<b>&&-Operator</b>\n";
if (test(false) && test(true)) {
    ;
}

echo "<b>&-Operator</b>\n";
if (test(false) & test(true)) {
    ;
}

echo "<b>and-Operator</b>\n";
if (test(false) and test(true)) {
    ;
}
?>
</pre>
```

Output:

```
||-Operator
I was executed
|-Operator
I was executed
I was executed
or-Operator
I was executed
&&-Operator
I was executed
&-Operator
I was executed
I was executed
and-Operator
I was executed
```

---

Note that | and & always execute the second part even when the output can't be true (&-Operator) anymore or can't become false (|-Operator) anymore.